# Reformat and parse huge text file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, file, parsing

I have some code to parse a text file after doing some reformatting.

```
 foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.*"))
 {
     contents = contents + File.ReadAllText(file).Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&quot;", "'");
     pos = contents.LastIndexOf("</event>");
     contents = contents.Substring(0, pos + 8);
 }

 contents = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root>" + contents + "</root>";

 XDocument doc = new XDocument();
 doc = XDocument.Parse(contents);
```

The file contains XML tags but is not formatted properly. Hence I reformat and store in a string variable `contents` . This string is loaded into an `XDocument` object and the program works smooth for small files (7-10 MB).

Now , there are files which are over 100MB in size and the code breaks with an out of memory exception.My code breaks at

```
contents = contents + File.ReadAllText(file).Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&quot;", "'");
```

What alternatives do I have to do the same operation with efficient file handling.

Comment: One becomes curious - if the file is over 100MB large, does it *really* need to be humanly readable?

Comment: In your current code every `Replace` causes another string allocation on an already huge in-memory string, No wonder you run out of memory. Use streams (`StreamReader`), and process in chunks.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, the key is to use streaming instead of full in-memory operations.

You could create a custom [`TextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx) subclass `FormattingReader` which wraps a `StreamReader` or similar and executes your formatting process on the fly while reading:

- Output the XML header
- Output the opening `<root>` tag
- Iterate over your files:

  - When you see `&lt;` or `&gt;` on the wrapped reader, output angular brackets instead
  - When you see the `</event>` tag, treat it as end of file
- Output the closing `</root>`

Then use the [`XmlReader.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z042k543.aspx) overload that takes a `TextReader` and pass an instance of your `FormattingReader`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are using `LastIndexOf` to find the `</event>` tag to omit. Thus my algorithm description does not fit and the idea may not help; it depends how much lookahead you need to do to determine whether you just saw the last `</event>`.

I don't delete it however because it may still give you another option to try.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to work with files more than 100 MB with XDocument because it stores everything in memory and performs all the operations in memory. Use XmlReader for that purpose.

Comment: Yes. While your parsing code may use some performance improvement, it is unlikely it causes the actual out of memory problem. It's really the XDocument use that's memory insensitive and thus causing your problem. If you don't want to deal with XmlReader (it's fairly low-level), check out XStreamingElement (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem with large files and after switching to XmlReader the memory consumption reduced may be about 10 times so it is good solution.

Comment: my code breaks at contents = contents + File.ReadAllText(file).Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&quot;", "'");

Comment: so before getting to XMLReader, i need to find a solution for formatting the file

Comment: It is important not to read all the contents at once and not to do mutiple copies of 100 Mb contents! Each Replace is a copy of 100 Mb.

Comment: In that case, use `StringBuilder` to hold the contents after each loop instead of concatenating strings. Using a `StreamReader` instead of `File.ReadAllText` will also help greatly. And if even that fails, I suppose you have to do a two-step process: in step 1 parse each file and write/append it to a temporary file (or possibly a `MemoryStream` although I'm not sure how better it is as compared to `StringBuilder`) and then in step 2 do the `XmlReader` process.

Comment: Agree that solution is in using streams + XmlReader